# SQL Server, Remove null values in a select case query

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code below generates around 300 rows, but only a small fraction of them has any value in column "Unit=3". The rest have null values, and hence many duplicate values in column "ekod" exists.

Does anyone know how to remove all rows with a null value in the column "unit=3"?

Best regards!

Result:

```
ekod    unit=3    
0004    NULL
0114    15
0114    NULL
0114    NULL
0120    NULL
0120    NULL
0120    46
0120    NULL
```

Code:

```
 select 
  A.ekod
    ,case when A.unit='3' then count(*) end AS [Unit=3]
  from [Stat_unitdata].[dbo].[XXX_YYY] A
  group by a.ekod, a.unit
  order by ekod
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sum`.

```
select 
A.ekod
,sum(case when a.unit='3' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Unit=3]
from [Stat_unitdata].[dbo].[XXX_YYY] A
group by a.ekod
order by ekod
```

Comment: Isn't it the `a.unit` in the group by causing the additional records?  so would `having A.Unit=3` help as well?  The lack of displaying a.unit in the select is hiding the fact that ekod is being duplicated from different a.units I think.

Comment: Darn those simpler and cleaner answers :P  but I think it may fail this way... I'm not sure how the case statement would work without the group by; but it may be fine since it's nested in a sum now.

Comment: @vkp case when a.unit='3' then 1 end gives the same result since 0 or null won't be added to the total

Comment: @vkp Thanks for all your answers! It helped a lot in solving my problems!

Answer (score 2):

As a note, if you don't care about `ekod`s with zero units:

```
select a.ekod, count(*) as [Unit=3]
from [Stat_unitdata].[dbo].[XXX_YYY] a
where a.unit = '3'
group by a.ekod
order by a.ekod;
```

This returns only `ekod` values that have at least one `unit` = '3'.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually, at first, needed to remove all the zero values but changed my mind later on!